# Can you put a mSATA SSD card into a ExpressCard Slot?

Tags: ssd, msata, expresscard

Obviously some sort of adapter would be required, but is it possible to fit a mSATA card into an ExpressCard slot?  Or equivalently does there exist an ExpressCard mSATA caddy or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Mini-SATA (abbreviated as mSATA) has a connector which is similar in appearance to a PCI Express Mini Card interface **but is not electrically compatible**.

This means you want either:

- A USB to mSATA convertor, or
- a PCI-e to mSATA convertor.

Both of which signals are provided by the expresscard interface.

This means extra electronics, which will make it very hard to fit both those, the mSATA drive and the nessecary padding/cables into a small expresscard slot.

So: Technically not impossible, but unlikely to work out in practice.